# show coupon discounted price on Checkout page :WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show the discounted price on checkout page after applying the coupon, discounted price is showing on cart page and payment gateway also but I want to show on checkout page also, so customer can easily understand they have applied coupon.

[image]

is there any way to show discounted price after applying coupon.

With this hook I am trying to get discounted price on checkout page

```
function woocommerce_order_review() {

 $totalp = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
 $totaldisc = $woocommerce->cart->get_total_discount();
 $resultp = $totalp - $totaldisc; 
 print_r($resultp);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
```

Comment: On a normal woocommerce checkout page, discounted totals are always displayed. Do you want to show discounted price for each product?

Comment: In my case it's not showing discounted price on checkout page it's showing discounted price only on cart page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php template and show discounted price as per your requirement by placing it under your themes folder.

---

You have cart items loop in review-order.php

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
```

with this content.

in this you will have subtotal in last table cell. There you can show the discounted price.

Or alternatively you can implement this hook. "woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal"

Comment: Hi thanks for reply but in my case it is showing original price on checkout page instead of discounted price..

Comment: That's why you can customize it from this template. You can show whatever price you want to show on checkout page.

Comment: Hi Can you please tell me how can I take discounted price and show on checkout page Thank you

Comment: I added more details

Comment: please check this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505056/woocommerce-create-new-discount-functionality

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question below is the code I just replicated review-order.php from 

**wp-content/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php** 
in my themes folder woocommerce 
**mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php**

and find this class **class="product-total"** replace whole php of this td with below mentioned code

```
      <?php function remove_currency($price) {
            return (double) preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]+/', '', $price);
        }?>
        <?php 
        $total = remove_currency(apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key )); 
        $discount = remove_currency(apply_filters( 'get_total_discount', WC()->cart->get_total_discount( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key )); 
        echo $total-$discount;
        ?>
```

Please correct me if I am wrong
  Thank you

Comment: It seems good. :) If this works for you, you can mark my answer correct.